# Is there a way of deal with unicodes in Python 2 and 3 simultaneously?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode, decode, encode

I am getting file names from the disk and I was wondering if there is a way of dealing with such unicode string that could work simultaneously.

Basically, in Python2 I would need to set the correct decoder for the string, while in Python3, I would need first to encode it, since in Python3 there is no decode method for string.

My workaround so far has been to include code like this:

```
if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    name = name.encode('utf-8')
name.decode('utf-8')
```

but hopefully there is a cleaner way to solve this

Comment: see this discussion: http://python-future.org/unicode_literals.html

Answer (score 1):

This works the same in Python 2 and Python 3.  Using Unicode strings for the in `os.listdir` will return Unicode filenames.  `os.walk` works similarly.  If you don't want to switch to `unicode_literals`, use `u'.'` instead.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals,print_function
import os

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    print(filename)
```

Comment: for some reasons, when I have the `from __future__ import unicode_literals` line, I experience the issue and the interpreter fails with `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte ...`, and if I do not have it, it seems to work BUT so far I am failing in reproducing the error in a small code sniplet, while in larger programs seems to be well reproducible, e.g. [here](https://bitbucket.org/norok2/hdu/src/397c743766acd415df1173781538f9cd725e8460/hdu/hdu.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: Your large program wasn't written to treat all strings as Unicode, so you won't be able to drop it in without accounting for it.  Somewhere, using `unicode_literals` you call something that expects bytes, and Python 2 is implicitly converting it using the `ascii` codec.  Being on Linux, you may want to leave all paths and filenames bytes, simply because your script would fail if it found any filenames not UTF-8-encoded.  On Windows the NTFS filesystem is natively UTF-16, so treating them all as Unicode makes sense.

Comment: I also thought that, but I am not able to track down where exactly this is happening. I believe that at the point it fails, I have only used `os.listdir`, `os.path.join`, `os.path.basename` and `str.startswith`, and none of them, neither singularly nor in combination, reproduces the issue. On the other hand, I use a recursive call to a function at some point, and I was wondering if it could be related to that.

Comment: I think I found out the culprit... the object returned by argparse is actually a str and not unicode.. I have opted for a try-except workaround:

`    try:
        base = base.encode('utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
    finally:
        base = base.decode('utf-8')`